# DataTable + DataGrid Data Binding Performance Againsts Custom Data Source Object + Data Grid

Tags: .net, performance, data-binding, datatable

In our industrial automation application, we need to capture and display the data in the milliseconds.

We have data binding between data grid control and a DataTable object. We have around three hundred records which needs to be display in the grid. So we update the 300 records every time we get the records.

Example

```
       TabularViewTable tvt = _presenter.WorkItem.Items.Get<TabularViewTable> ("TabularViewTable");

        foreach (DataRow row in tvt.Rows)
        {
            row["Value"] = GetDataFast(row["Name"]);                
        }
```

After connecting 10 devices, the CPU usage goes 15%. How to improve the performance using DataTable or using some custom data source

Regards,

Krishgy

Answer (score 2):

You should seriously reconsider your user interface:

- Is it really necessary to display 300 values? Ordinary human cannot concentrate on more than 7 things simultaneously,
- Even if you lower number of parameters, there is frequency of refresh that seems to high to be practical.

You probably should do following:

- create a dashboard with graphical representation of most important data (graphs, gauges, ...)
- create drill down forms and reports, so that user can see what happened with system in any given period

Answer (score 0):

For starters you need to switch from a DataTable to a DataReader as it is much faster.  Secondly I would look at a Lazy Loading architecture.  Bind 50 entries and when they scroll to the bottom Bind/Load another 50.